# Prevent a program (steam) to start for a time period

Tags: macos, applications

Out of habit I play games, but it's something that I'd like to change without deleting all of the games I have. So I was wondering if it's possible to prevent steam from starting in the same way there are apps that block you from accessing the internet.

Comment: There are lots of third party apps for that. At the end of the day, if you're setting up a system to stop yourself, you'd easily beat it if not spend loads of time trying to. Simple solution is work on your self control.

Answer (score 1):

How do you launch Steam?  I think you could create some kind of scheduled task in Automator/cron that either moves Steam.app to another location (preventing your Dock icon from working) or, if you use Spotlight, somehow breaking the application bundle.

For example, you could disable with:

```
mkdir ~/NoSteam/
mv /Applications/Steam.app/Contents ~/NoSteam/
```

And re-enable with:

```
mv ~/NoSteam/Contents/ /Applications/Steam.app
```

Kludgy but effective.

Comment: I suggest `chmod -x /Applications/Steam.app/Contents/MacOS/Steam` to disable it, and `+x` to reenable it. This uses features as intended.

Comment: Max's suggestions is reasonable - more graceful than mine!